# Error when using Qt, VC++ and OpenCV library

Tags: qt, visual-c++, opencv

I have this error in Qt when useing it with VC++ code and opencv library.

```
SXS: Invalid parameter(s) passed to FindActCtxSection*()
   dwFlags = 0x00000001
   ReturnedData = 0022AAFC
      ->cbSize = 0
SXS: Invalid parameter(s) passed to FindActCtxSection*()
   dwFlags = 0x00000001
   ReturnedData = 0022AAFC
      ->cbSize = 0
SXS: Invalid parameter(s) passed to FindActCtxSection*()
   dwFlags = 0x00000001
   ReturnedData = 0022AAFC
      ->cbSize = 0
SXS: Invalid parameter(s) passed to FindActCtxSection*()
   dwFlags = 0x00000001
   ReturnedData = 0022AAFC
      ->cbSize = 0
```

I googled it and found something related to DLL but I did not understand anything. Could someone please explain it?

Answer (score 1):

You are using Qt and Opencv?
This looks like an [MFC bug](http://blog.m-ri.de/index.php/2011/04/14/bug-black-patchday-for-all-os-from-xp-and-later-3-mfc-8-0-vc-2005-or-mfc-9-0-vc-2008-linked-dynamically-to-the-mfc-may-not-find-the-mfc-language-dlls-after-installation-of-the-security-packs-d/)

Comment: MFC is a Microsoft C++ library for writing GUIs (like Qt but horrible). If you are using Qt then deselect any MFC settings in the compiler properties

Comment: How can I do what did you say? please help me , really I did not know how to do it? thank you,thank you.

Comment: properties->general->use of MFC and make sure it says using standard windows libraries.

Comment: sorry but there is no ( properties ) in Qtcreator. sorry.